# Shell script to read line after first 840 characters

Tags: linux

I am trying to create a script to read a line of a file after first 840 characters. I am getting lots of information on how to get first few chars of a line using cut but not getting any info on how to get chars after first few chars in a line. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Vijay. Could you show us what have you tried already? Some code would be great and you should also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `python -c 'f = open("filename"); f.read(840); print f.readline(),'`

Comment: Thanks Majilik for your reply. I am not having any idea how to do this. Right now the only code I have created is to go through the file and get the charcters count on each line.
`#!/bin/ksh
file="/root/passwd"
while read line
do
     len=`echo -n "$line" | wc -c;`
     common=840;
     lineitem=61;
`

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I need it in shell.

Comment: @Vijay: 1. that is why I've posted it as a comment and not an answer 2. Though, formally, it is a complete shell command.